# How to connect WCF Service to a UWP Appl In Another computer

Tags: c#, wcf, uwp

I wanted to connect a WCF service to a UWP application. When it is on the same computer it works fine. But when I use it on another computer it doesn't work. It cannot be found when I tried to add it using Add Service Reference. I'm new to WCF. If you can give some explained details, I will really appreciate that.

The current configuration file in the WCF Service host (App.Config)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <configuration>
    <startup> 
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".
                        NETFramework,Version=v4.8" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
      <bindings></bindings>
      <client></client>
      <services>
        <service name="PMService1.MainService"
                 behaviorConfiguration="mexBehavior">
          <endpoint address="MainServiceReference"
                    binding="basicHttpBinding"
                    contract="PMService1.IMainService">
          </endpoint>
          <endpoint address="MainServiceReference"
                    binding="netTcpBinding"
                    contract="PMService1.IMainService">
          </endpoint>
          <endpoint address="mex"
                    binding="mexHttpBinding"
                    contract="IMetadataExchange">
          </endpoint>
          <host>
            <baseAddresses>
              <add baseAddress="http://Pasan-Desktop:8086"/>
              <add baseAddress="net.tcp://Pasan-Desktop:8090"/>
            </baseAddresses>
          </host>
        </service>
      </services>
      <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior name="mexBehavior">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
      </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: It seems that this address: `http://Pasan-Desktop:8086` is not accessible from everywhere.

Comment: Is `Pasan-Desktop` the 2nd PC? Can you `ping` it from the first PC? If yes can you connect e.g. `telnet Pasan-Desktop 8086`?

Comment: @HasaniH It didn't work... But SSH and developer portal works. Is it something to do with the firewall?

Comment: @PasanAnuththara, yes this could be your Windows Firewall or some other network device, really can't say without knowing your setup.

Comment: I managed to fix that by creating a inbound firewall rule for those ports.